# Remove character from a File

Tags: unix

Using UNIX Scripting it is possible to remove all the firsts characters from a file till a specific character is found ?

I have a file with "garbage" at the beginning. I want to remove that "garbage, meaning that all the character till the first "{" must be removed. How can I do this ?

Comment: So you want *us* to *clean the garbarge*?

Comment: Yes ... remove everything till the "{"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat file.txt | grep -A 1000000000 '{' | sed '1 s/^[^{]*//'
```

This will print the changed contents (i. e. without the garbage) to `stdout`.  You can *redirect* this using `> outfile.txt` appended to the command:

```
cat file.txt | grep -A 1000000000 '{' | sed '1 s/^[^{]*//' > outfile.txt
```

And if you want to change the file in-place, this can be done by renaming the `outfile.txt` to the original name `file.txt` afterwards:

```
mv outfile.txt file.txt
```